# onLocationChanged not called if GPS disabled or if not sharing location with Google

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I detect location changes even when the GPS is disabled? I know it won't be accurate, but that's ok.

Here is my code:

```java
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
        implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

private MapView mMapView;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(3000)         // 3 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }


    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    this,  // ConnectionCallbacks
                    this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("REMOTE_LOCATION_CHANGED", "Location = " + location);

        // Only works if I do enable GPS and allow location sharing with Google (if I disagree to share the location or if I disable GPS, this event is never called)

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                REQUEST,
                this);  // LocationListener
    }

}
```

As I pointed in a comment, the onLocationChanged event is never called if the GPS is disabled or if its enabled but sharing location with Google is not allowed.

Why?

### UPDATE

I've updated the onConnected method to check if GPS is available before using high accuracy, and if it's not available I tried to use both PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY and PRIORITY_LOW_POWER, but it still works only if I enable the GPS.
If you use an app like Foursquare (now Swarm), it'll try to get a location even with GPS disabled. How do I do the same thing?

One more thing, I tried to use the Location service to getLastKnownLocation, however it's null.

Comment: your priority is set to high accuracy aka GPS

Comment: One more case of bad name method in Android SDK, if I'm setting a priority, I'm not creating a limit to use only GPS. But that's another discussion.

Comment: @juliano do u get the location if gps is off

Answer (score 1):

According to the official Android docs

" To obtain the user location in your application, you can use both GPS and the Network Location Provider, or just one.
Getting user location in Android works by means of callback. You indicate that you'd like to receive location updates from the

```
LocationManager
```

("Location Manager") by calling

```
requestLocationUpdates(),
```

passing it a

```
LocationListener
```

Your

```
LocationListener
```

must implement several callback methods that the Location Manager calls when the user location changes or when the status of the service changes"

For more details and example refer to

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 1):

If GPS/Location is disabled you will never receive onLocationChanged events

However, LocationClient has a function called getLastLocation() which you can call to get the last known location if you don't care about the accuracy.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation()